# Issue in prototype js

Tags: php, javascript, sql, prototype

I'm trying to update the database using the ajax, but getting some error below error if if see in the console.

```
INSERT INTO customers(customerName,contactLastName,contactFirstName, phone, addressLine1,addressLine2, city, state, postalCode,country,salesRepEmployeeNumber,creditLimit) VALUES (,,,, ,,,,,,,)
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',,, ,,,,,,,)' at line 1
```

I have hilighted the JS code which contains the prototype ajax code and then the php code which contains the insert details

can you guys help me out in this issue

My site link

```
http://localhost/fashionsite/customer.php
```

my js code`enter code here`

```
$('submit_btn').observe('click', function(ev) {
    $('customerdetails').request({
        method: 'get',
        onFailure: function() { 
        alert("failed");
        },      
        onComplete: function(details){
            console.log(details.responseText);

            //alert("inserted success fully");
            //$("content_updated").update(details.responseText);
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

my php code

```
<?php

include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';
//$sNO = $_POST["sNO"];
//$customerNumber = $_POST["customerNumber"];
$customerNames = $_POST["customerName"];
$contactLastName = $_POST["contactLastName"];
$contactFirstName = $_POST["contactFirstName"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$addressLine1 = $_POST["addressLine1"];
$addressLine2 = $_POST["addressLine2"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$postalCode = $_POST["postalCode"];
$country = $_POST["countryText"];
$salesRepEmployeeNumber = $_POST["salesRepEmployeeNumber"];
$creditLimit = $_POST["creditLimit"];

/*echo $customerNumber .'<br/>'. $customerName .'<br/>'. $contactLastName .'<br/>'. $contactFirstName .'<br/>'. $phone .'<br/>'. $addressLine1 .'<br/>'. $addressLine2 .'<br/>'. $city .'<br/>'. $state .'<br/>'. $postalCode .'<br/>'. $country .'<br/>'. $salesRepEmployeeNumber .'<br/>'. $creditLimit;*/


$sql = "INSERT INTO customers(customerName,contactLastName,contactFirstName, phone, addressLine1,addressLine2, city, state, postalCode,country,salesRepEmployeeNumber,creditLimit) VALUES ($customerNames,$contactLastName,$contactFirstName,$phone, $addressLine1,$addressLine2,$city,$state,$postalCode,$country,$salesRepEmployeeNumber,$creditLimit)";

print $sql;


//echo $sql .'<br/><br/><br/><br/>';

if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

?>
```

I have hilighted the JS code which contains the prototype ajax code and then the php code which contains the insert details

Comment: Updated the error which i got in the mail post

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear.

Comment: When people answer your questions here in ways that help you, you should pick the best answer and click the big checkmark next to it. That signifies that you **accept** the answer.

Comment: Also, at some point (before you're actually keeping track of real customers) you should address the tremendous SQL Injection security vulnerability in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send `GET` request, but try in php get values from `$_POST` array. So then in sql you get `'VALUES (,,,, ,,,,,,,)'` and it is cause of error.

Comment: You mean to say instead of "get" i have to use "post"

Comment: What i was doing is in the form i was adding post and in ajax i was using get, so that is the problem. Now i removed the post in form and used get in the ajax it works fine. ThNks